# Why is the 4th ghost the only ghost that isn't violent?

Tags: character, thirteen-ghosts

I was just wondering, why isn't Jean, the 4th ghost, violent? The psychic said that all the ghosts are violent because they died a violent death and that's why Cyrus wanted them, so why is she the only one who isn't violent?

Comment: Changed the title just in case, as I'm not sure if the name of *Arthur*'s wife is mentioned before the reveal about her role as one of the ghosts.

Comment: As a note, this *exact* question was also asked on [Movie Mistakes](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film1633/questions).

Comment: Based on the title, I am shocked this isn't a question about Pac-Man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that it had to do with her connection to them, since she was their mother/wife.  None of the characters shared any similar connection to the ghosts.

Also, Jean is the only one that died in a non-violent, non-demeaning manner.  Yes, she died in a fire, but she was saving her family, not trying to murder them.

Comment: *"Jean is the only one that died in a non-violent, non-demeaning manner."* - That is true, yet in this case she wouldn't even work at all as a ghost for driving the machine. (In the end I guess they (the filmmakers) just needed an additional connection to the family, while still not depicting her as evil).

Answer (score 3):

13 ghosts are required to make a dark Zodiac. As in the zodiac there are 12 zodiac signs, which says that every member who belongs to that sign has some specific traits. Similarly, we can assume that the 13 ghosts required for making Dark zodiac should also have different traits. For example, the 13th ghost is Arthur, whose soul is required, but he is also nonviolent.

Most of the ghost are violent, but they have their own traits that make them different from each other. The **The Withered Lover** is a spirit made of sacrifice, so she doesn't have any vengeance towards anybody, which made her nonviolent.

Comment: *"So The Withered Lover is a spirit made of sacrifice"* - In which way did she die out of sacrifice? She burned in their house but I'm not sure it's mentioned anywhere that she sacrificed herself for something or somebody in that fire. Sacrifice was the role of *Arthur* to take.

Comment: @ChristianRau she sacrificed herself in saving her family from fire.

Answer (score 1):

As is stated on Wikipedia, ghost #4 is called ***[The Withered Lover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Ghosts)*** ...

It is written as such:

> The Withered Lover is Jean Kriticos, Arthur's wife. She was burned severely while saving her family from a devastating house fire, and died of her wounds in the hospital. Her ghost initially appears in a hospital gown, hooked up to an IV pole and showing severe burns on her face. However, after the destruction of the machine, her ghost is wearing her normal clothes and her burns have vanished. **Unlike the other ghosts, she is not a vengeful spirit and tries to help her family.**

Comment: Yet this doesn't really answer the actual question of *why* she behaves this way, while still having been chosen a a ghost for the machine (which *Dennis* describes as violent spirits).